# MongoDB query a document by it's nested array of objects and update all objects inside document's array that matchs query

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So I have the following documents in a collection.

```
{
       _id: "1",
       quantity: 0,
       array: [{name: "test1a", quantity: 10}, {name: "test1a", quantity: 1}, {name: "test1b", quantity: 10}, {name: "test1c", quantity: 1}]
}

{
       _id: "2",
       quantity: 0,
       array: [{name: "test2a", quantity: 10}, {name: "test2b", quantity: 10}, {name: "test2c", quantity: 1}]
}

{
       _id: "3",
       quantity: 0,
       array: [{name: "test3a", quantity: 10}, {name: "test3b", quantity: 10}, {name: "test3c", quantity: 1}]
}
```

What I wanted was to query all documents in the collection whose it's array contains objects with name = "test1a" and update those object quantity property with a new value.

Comment: update with what?

Comment: @Krishna with a new int value using $set operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
db.collection.find({"array.name": "test1a"}).forEach(function(doc){       
var myArray = doc.array;
for (var i in myArray){
    if(myArray[i].name == "test1a"){
        myArray[i].quantity = myArray[i].quantity +1;        
    }
}
 db.collection.update({"_id": doc._id},{$set: {"array":myArray}});
});
```

Comment: I received the following error: cannot use the part (array of array.quantity) to traverse the element.

Comment: The problem is, array.&.quantity only updates the first element inside the array. What I want is to update all array elements that matchs name = "test1a".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
db.test.updateMany(
    { "array.name": "test1a" }, 
    { "$set": { "array.$[elem].quantity": "newvalue" } },
    { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.name": "test1a" }] }
)
```

Comment: The problem is, array.&.quantity only updates the first element inside the array. What I want is to update all array elements that matchs name = "test1a".

Comment: I got the following error = cannot use the part (array of array.$[elem].quantity) to traverse the element.

Comment: did you use arrayfilters option?

Comment: Yes, I did use arrayFilters option.

Comment: I tested the query and then posted here. Can you post your full query

Comment: Well, I'm using this query in a different collection. At my collection I'm doing this way:                                                           
                    collection.update({
                        "seller_id": store_id, "variations.sku": sku
                    }, {$set:{"variations.$[elem].quantity": stock}}, { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.sku": sku }]}

Comment: Possibility to receive that error is that your variations is not having similar structure in some of the documents. I assume. Post if you find a solution.

Comment: The error is this: "details": {
        "name": "MongoError",
        "message": "cannot use the part (variations of variations.$[elem].quantity) to traverse the element ({variations: [ { sku: \"henrique\", quantity: 113, ean: null, images: [ null ], specifications: [ { key: null, value: null } ] }, { sku: \"henrique\", quantity: 0, ean: null, images: [ null ], specifications: [ { key: null, value: null } ] } ]})",
        "driver": true,
        "index": 0,
        "code": 16837
    }

Comment: The document structure: {
 "_id" : "118228163637414",
 "is_active" : true,
 "title" : "Test",
 "description" : "Test",
 "status" : "Novo",
 "quantity" : 120,
 "units_reserved" : 0,
 "variations" : [
  {
   "sku" : "henrique",
   "quantity" : 113,
   "ean" : null,
   "images" : [
    null
   ],
   "specifications" : []
  },
  {
   "sku" : "henrique",
   "quantity" : 0,
   "ean" : null,
   "images" : [
    null
   ],
   "specifications" : []
  }
 ],
 "seller_id" : "z8dWSiEJBPQe5ory9"
}